# Unable to remove a default image

Tags: media

I have an Image field for a node. I added a default image, but now I want to use a different default image.

When I click the Remove button, I get the following AJAX error:

> An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information
>   follows. Path:
>   /file/ajax/instance/settings/default_image/form-h8XGqyiOrbYg2szWDEf3u-Ch9LDl7xvajwpG-3cLx5g
>   StatusText: n/a ResponseText:  Error   Error message Recoverable fatal
>   error: Argument 2 passed to drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be an
>   array, null given, called in /var/www/includes/form.inc on line 2519
>   and defined in drupal_array_set_nested_value() (line 6570 of
>   /var/www/includes/common.inc). The website encountered an unexpected
>   error. Please try again later.
>
> ReadyState: undefined

Comment: Maybe try using one of the themes that ships with Drupal for your admin pages. Only other thing I can think is to manually delete the image causing problems from the server.

Comment: I always use a standard Drupal theme for Admin. I thought about manually removing the image from the filesystem, but was afraid that would just end up causing more problems down the road.

Comment: It  is any conflict created some module which is creating issue in image upload.
Please try disabling the newly added module if it was working fine before.

Comment: I am not sure if I have ever tried to remove a default image before. If so, dozens of modules have been added since then.

Comment: I assume you're using the latest Drupal core/contrib modules? You could always move the file, and if it causes more problems, put it back, then start disabling image and field related modules until the problem goes away to isolate the issue.